# passing parameters from external file (template) to puppet script

Tags: ruby, templates, puppet

Hi I'm trying to execute an exe file using puppet script. My exe file is accepting 3 parameters like param1, param2 and param3. All I want is to pass these parameters through external file. How can I do this?

Here is my sample code:

```
exec { "executing exe file":
  command => 'copyfile.exe "DestinatoinPath" "sourcefilename" "destinationfilename" ',
}
```

All I want is to pass all these values from external file and use it here.

Can someone help me to resolve this

Here is my trail:

Here is my directory structure:

```
puppet\modules\mymodule\manifests\myfile.pp and 
puppet\modules\mymodule\templates\params.erb 

and my erb file is having a value of path ex: d:\test1.txt e:\test1.txt testfilename 

$myparams = template("mymodule/params.erb") 

exec { "executing exe file":
  command => '$myparams',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT:*

The root of the problem was trying to call the module manifest directly, thus the template lookup failed. The solution was not to use a module and specify the full template path.

---

There are 2 main ways to go about it:

**Declare the variables in scope**

```
#acceptable for a throwaway manifest
$path = "DestinationPath"
$source = "sourcefilename"
$destination "destinationfilename"

exec { "executing exe file":
    command => 'copyfile.exe ${path} ${source} ${destination}',
}
```

**Wrap it in a parameterized class/defined type**

```
# parameterized class, included only once
class executing_exe_file ($path, $source, $destination) {
    exec { "executing exe file":
        command => 'copyfile.exe ${path} ${source} ${destination}',
    }
}
```

OR

```
# defined resource, can be repeated multiple times
define executing_exe_file ($path, $source, $destination) {
    exec { "executing exe file":
        command => 'copyfile.exe ${path} ${source} ${destination}',
    }
}
```

THEN

```
executing_exe_file { "executing exe file":
    path: "DestinationPath",
    source: "sourcefilename",
    destination: "destinationfilename",
}
```

Also as a side note, you have to make sure `copyfile.exe` is fully qualified.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Here I want to store these destination, source and path values in a separate file instead of putting in the same script and want to access from there (like .erb file). So that I can change that file every time when ever required. So there is no need of open the actual puppet script. I tried to put these values in template folder and trying to access. But it is failing.

Comment: @jestges Where are you putting the values that you require? Can you update your question with the puppet code that fetches the value?

Comment: I'm putting my values in template folder like params.erb and trying to access like $myparams = template("mymodule/params.erb")

Comment: That's an... interesting way to pass parameters. Have you considered using `hiera` instead? Anyway, can you update your question with all the puppet code and module directory structure for further inspection?

Comment: Here is my directory structure: puppet\modules\mymodule\manifests\myfile.pp and puppet\modules\mymodule\templates\params.erb and my erb file is having a value of path ex: d:\test1.txt e:\test1.txt testfilename

Comment: Can you edit your question with the information you've provided instead? Trying to avoid an extended discussion in the comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42092/discussion-between-jestges-and-xiankai)